# OpenGraph - Not receiving all data

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Login Button in my application and requesting following things:

```
LoginButton facebookLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
    "email",
    "user_birthday",
    "user_likes",
    "user_location",
    "user_relationships"
));
```

But I am not getting `user_likes` in the UserObject, what I get is this:

```
{
    "birthday":"...",
    "location":{"id":"...","name":"..."},
    "locale":"...",
    "link":"...",
    "updated_time":"...",
    "relationship_status":"...",
    "id":"...",
    "languages":[...],
    "first_name":"...",
    "timezone": ...,
    "email":"...",
    "verified":true,
    "name":"...",
    "last_name":"...",
    "gender":"...."
}
```

I tried some other permissions as well, but I only receive these details.

Answer (score 0):

Not all fields are returned by default from the /me endpoint. You need to add something like ?fields=likes to your request.